# Displaying(redirecting) to View from WebGrid with Parameter to DropDownList on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, webgrid

How to I pass an ID from my WebGrid to my ActionResult:

Here is my WebGrid code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LandingPage", "ProjectDetail"))
{
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Projectmodel, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 3, defaultSort: "ProjectName");

<div id="gridContent" style="font-family: Arial; padding: 20px;" class="col-md-12">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    columns: grid.Columns(
              grid.Column("ProjectName", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.ProjectName.ToString())),
              grid.Column(columnName: "DesignerName", header: "Designer Name"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "ProjectType", header: "Project Type"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "FluidType", header: "Fluid Type"),
              grid.Column(columnName: "PipeMaterial", header: "Pipe Material"),
              grid.Column(header: "", format: (item) =>
              {
                  var link = Html.ActionLink("View/Edit", "LandingPage", new { pkiProjectID = item.pkiProjectID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default2" });
                  return Html.Raw(link);
              })), mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)

    <h2>Project Details: </h2>
    @if (grid.HasSelection)
    {
        var emp = (AirFlo_Size_Programme.Models.ProjectDetail)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;
        <p><b>Project Name:</b> @emp.ProjectName</p>
        <p><b>Designer Name:</b> @emp.DesignerName</p>
        <p><b>Project Type:</b> @emp.ProjectType</p>
        <p><b>Fluid Type:</b> @emp.FluidType</p>
        <p><b>Pipe Material:</b> @emp.PipeMaterial</p>
    }
</div>
}
```

My `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult ProjectInformation(ProjectInformationController model, int id)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        using (RexusTradingEntities RTE = new RexusTradingEntities())
        {
            var ProjectData = (from PI in RTE.ProjectInformations.ToArray()
                               orderby PI.Project_Name
                               select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Text = PI.Project_Name,
                                   Value = PI.pkiProjectID.ToString()
                               }).ToArray();
            ViewBag.ProjectList = ProjectData;
        }



        return View();
   }
```

I then want to use this ID to select an item in a DropDownList in the `View` I am directing to, which is something im also not sure how to do.

But now the id is passed in the URL - I dont want this. I want to pass the Parameter to my ActionResult and want my URL to stay "clean" - How do I do this ?

On a side note, im looking for css that can style my WebGrid nicely(Possibly rounded corners etc.) - is this possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours, I finally got it to work :

```
Model:

public class ProjectInformationViewModel
{
    public int SelectedProjectID { get; set; }
    public SelectList ProjectList2 { get; set; }

    //Other Properties required for View added below
}

Controller:

public ActionResult ProjectInformation(ProjectDetailsViewModels model, int ProjectID)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        var PIVM = new ProjectInformationViewModel();

        using (RexusTradingEntities RTE = new RexusTradingEntities())
        {
            var ProjectData = (from PI in RTE.ProjectInformations.ToArray()
                               orderby PI.Project_Name
                               select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Text = PI.Project_Name.ToString(),
                                   Value = PI.pkiProjectID.ToString(),
                                   Selected = true
                               }).ToArray();

            PIVM.SelectedProjectID = ProjectID;

            PIVM.ProjectList = new SelectList(ProjectData, "Value", "Text", ProjectID);
        }

        return View(PIVM);
   }
```

(The ProjectID parameter is coming from my Landing Page WebGrid selection)

```
View:

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProjectID, new SelectList(Model.ProjectList, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedProjectID), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I hope this helps someone else as well.